# PUT request to update data in a website

Tags: php, curl

I want to update price field in a website using Curl PUT request. But I am not being able to figure out the error in my code. It will be great help if you can find the error. Below is my code.

```
$api_request_url = 'http://example.com/variants/SOMETHING';


$method_name = 'PUT';

$header = array(
"Accept: application/json, text/plain",
"Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8",
"Connection: keep-alive",
"Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5",
"Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
"Content-Length: 82",
"Referer: http://seller.example.com/catalog",
"Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate"
);

$payload = array(
//"variant:  'YEL510044' , 6",//
'price' => '600',
//"original_price: 999"//
);
$data_string = json_encode($payload);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);



curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_request_url);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);


$api_response = curl_exec($ch);


$api_response_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
echo "$api_response";

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: You have not shown us the actual error message.  How does it fail?

Comment: You're not getting an error message? Add `ini_set('display_errors',"1");` at the top of your script. Then edit your question and add the error message.

Comment: I am just getting the blank page and when i check the data on live website, there is no update in data there.

Answer (score 2):

You try change code:

```
$data_string = json_encode($payload);
```

to

```
$data_string = http_build_query($payload);
```

Comment: I changed the statement. In fact i tried this function earlier. but it didn't worked either. I am just getting the blank page and no error message.

Comment: you change array header "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8", to 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Comment: Nothing changed, same problem.

Comment: It's worked please check

    $curl = curl_init($api_request_url);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));

    $data_string = http_build_query($payload);

            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");

        $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        return $curl_response;

Comment: Still the update operation is not done by this.

Comment: $payload = array('variant','sku' =>"YEL510044",'variant','count_on_hand' => 2,'price' => 449,'original_price' => 999);

Comment: the above way to enter multidimensional associative array is wrong or right? I think this is creating an issue here.

Comment: Input $payload = array('count_on_hand' => 2,'price' => 449);
You try debug http_build_query($payload); and see result 
if result equal count_on_hand=2&price=449 is right.

Comment: {"variant":{"sku":"YEL510044","count_on_hand":2},"price":449,"original_price":999}   This is the actual array, Can u tell me how to implement it in the program

Comment: the message should be{"status":"success","message":"ok"}                         but i am getting this {"status":"fail","message":"sku not found"}

Comment: you need have to convert {"variant":{"sku":"YEL510044","count_on_hand":2},"price":449,"original_price":99‌​9} to an array like $payload = array('count_on_hand' => 2,'price' => 449)

Comment: i have done it using json postdata query. By the way, thanks man for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you should try:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT,  true);

in place of

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');